# Using Java, what other libraries are avalible for easily converting CSV files to DBF (dBase/xBase)?

Tags: android, library, java, database, csv

I am currently writing an android app that interfaces with database files and was considering a way to export data neatly without errors. Currently every library I can find has one issue or another when I try to use it: Dumping records with extra characters attached, corruption of files, no available documentation.

I could always write the script myself but I think it would be much better to have a tested library to use.

Comment: As importing CSV files into ADB is not a common use case I don't think that you will find a library that implements this and that meets quality criteria. If you have problems with certain libraries you should better create a question about those libraries, describing in detail what problems you were facing.

Comment: Will your android app be receiving .csv files that will be stored locally as xbase files? Or will it just parse the .csv files and transmit them to a server that will store them as xbase? This it critical because there are tools like FoxInCloud as well as some of the WestWinds libraries that can run on servers for you. Depending on how you are designing your application, the library may have to run on android or could run on a remote server (as a microservice, web site, DB server, etc.) in which case non android based libraries may work. And you don't really explain why it has to be xbase in t

Comment: @FletcherJohnson This will be stored locally then retrieved by another external program. All that matters is that the CSV files stored on disk can be converted to xBase. The reason for xBase is that this app is being created as a legacy solution to replace a certain piece of software which uses xBase as its primary database. This legacy software has become more and more buggy as hardware changes increase over time, rendering it almost unusable. The number of files to convert is small, about 10, but I would rather have a universal converter than having to hard code each xBase file structure.

Comment: You should indicate what libraries you have tried, and their specific limitation/flaw. And your Question is not clear: Were you having problems with the libraries reading CSV or the libraries writing DBF files?